# Get the minimum value from a list

Tags: mysql

I want to get the minimum of a list of numbers in MYSQL

```
select min(1,9,20,..);
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The function you are looking for is called [`LEAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least):

```
select least(2,4,6,8,1,2,3,4) as result;
+--------+
| result |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible

```
SELECT MIN( mark ) FROM `student`
```

given that you have a student table with a mark column in it.

or use Least as posted by @Ike Walker